# How to include class diagrams in Doxygen pdf?

Tags: graphics, pdf, diagrams

I'm doing a programming project in college and I documenting my code with Doxygen. The program generates two folders, *html* and *latex*.  In the *html* folder, there are some class diagrams (png files) I would like to include in the pdf file that I can generate from the tex files in the *latex* folder.

I've followed this guide http://asktheoracle.com/blog/how-to-ad-graphics-in-doxygen-pdf-files-2/ which basically states that I need to add `\graphicspath{{../html/}}` to the `refman.tex` file but it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

EDIT: I hope this isn't a platform dependent problem. Just for reference, I'm running Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, I have Doxygen, Graphviz and MacTeX installed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange! It would be helpful if you could provide a working example of the code you've come up with so far. Which LaTeX packages are loaded by default in the preamble of `refman.tex`?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for taking time to help me. I uploaded everything to my Dropbox account. You can take a look at my files directly. The folder named doxygen contains my source files and the docs folder contains the html and tex folders generated by Doxygen. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1829895/code.tar.gz